# What does it mean when $(a+bi)\times(a-bi)=1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

What does it mean when $(a+bi)\times(a-bi)=1$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, is there any special significance to complex number $\times$ complex conjugate equaling $1$?

Comment: It means they both live on the unit circle.

Comment: oh wow, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: It means that $1$ is the modulus of that complex number, though not sure whether this is the "special" you meant.

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a practice in programming, not in Mathematics.

Comment: You should see it more deeply. Do the multiplication out and you see that you get $a^2+b^2$; those are the squares of the $x$ and the $y$ coordinates. But if $a^2+b^2=1$, then also $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$, and that’s the length of the line from the origin to the point $(a,b)$. Get the picture? If not, draw it, and Know.

Comment: If $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$, and $z \in \Bbb{C} ~: z = (a + ib)$, then $\left(\overline{z}\right)$ denotes the conjugate of $z$ and is equal to $(a - ib)$.  Further, the modulus of $z$, which is written as $|z|$ and refers to the magnitude of the distance of $z$ from the origin is computed as $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.$  Then, it is easy to demonstrate that for any complex $z$, you have that $$z \times \left(\overline{z}\right) = \left( ~|z| ~\right)^2.$$

Comment: Note that if $z,w$ are two complex numbers, and $z \neq 0$, then $$\frac{w}{z}$$ may be evaluated as $$\frac{w}{z} \times \frac{\overline{z}}{\overline{z}} = \frac{w \times \overline{z}}{|z|^2}.$$  Since it is assumed that $z \neq 0$, the denominator in the fraction above must be positive.  Further, if $|z| = 1$, then the denominator in the fraction above must equal $1$.

Answer (score 1):

In a general field $F$ when you have that for $a,b\in F$ $a\cdot b=1$ then this means by definition that $b$ is the inverse of $a$ or vice versa. So in your case this means that $\bar z$ is the inverse of $z$ for $z\in \Bbb{C}$. But now you can ask when does this happens?

I claim that $z\cdot \bar z=1 \Rightarrow |z|=1$.

Indeed if $z\cdot \bar z=1$ then $z=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ (remark $z\neq 0$) then $|z|=\left|\frac{1}{\bar z}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|\Leftrightarrow |z|^2=1\Rightarrow |z|=1$

Comment: Easier: $z\overline z = |z|^2$, so $z\overline z = 1 \implies |z|^2=1 \implies |z|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$z = a + bi = re^{i\theta} \implies \bar z = a - bi = re^{-i\theta} \implies z\cdot \bar z=r^2 = |z|^2$$

$$\therefore z\cdot \bar z = 1 \implies a^2 + b^2 = 1 \iff r^2 = 1 \implies r = 1$$

Hence, in the Argand plane, $z$ and $\bar z$ and their reflections about the $y$-axis lie on the unit circle, where $\bar z$ is a reflection of $z$ about the $x$-axis. In other words, $(a, b), (a, -b), (-a, b)$ and $(-a, -b)$ lie on the unit circle. Furthermore, $-1 \leq a,b \leq 1$.